# How to interpret negative factor loadings and residual variances in SEM?

Tags: factor-analysis, residuals, structural-equation-modeling

I've been trying to fit a SEM model, using misconceptions and the correct conception as latent variables.

My instrument is a set of items that ask a binary yes or no question. (Is something in a particular category?) The correct conception would have all items that would be correct if yes was chosen loaded onto it and the misconception would have all items we would expected to be answered yes if the subject had the given misconception. In this case, there would be some overlap between the misconception and correct conception factor loadings. i.e. cross-loading.

Is cross-loading in SEM acceptable? and if so, how would I interpret a negative cross loading and negative residual variance for the items?

Comment: i dont understand your model, but for your last question: a negative residual variance is most likely indicating a problem in your model specification.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for not being as clear as I could have. What I meant was that, there exists a set of items. These items are all indicative of a latent variable (Having a correct conception). A subset of these items are also indicative of another latent variable (A particular misconception). This subset of items would cross load onto both latent variables mentioned. I hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: with a SEM (or CFA) you are testing whether the data fits a model based on your hypothesis, so if your hypothesis is that there are cross-loadings then this is ok - you can fit without cross-loadings and compare fit statistics. Is it sensible to have two factors - conception and misconception  Might be worth doing a EFA?